# Вырезать кадры из видео

Tags: c++, c, видео, opencv, ffmpeg

На вход подается видео с большим содержанием *белых* кадров. Их надо вырезать.

Кадров белых может быть 5-90% всего видео. Поэтому ручками их вырезать не вариант. У меня *opencv* составляет *txt-документ* с номерами кадров, можно указывать время кадра, или хранить данные в массиве.

Думал, с помощью *ffmpeg* их вырезать, но столкнулся с проблемой, что вырезать с помощью *txt* он не может. Или я не нашел такой вариант.

Как решить данную проблему?

Может быть, другой проигрыватель использовать, или сам *opencv* умеет так делать?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV умеет работать с FFmpeg: использует его муксер и кодеки. Либо, использовать самому libavformat, libavcodec и иже с ними (либы FFmpeg), декодировать кадр, отдавать OpenCV, детектировать, что он "белый" пропускать его в итоговом кодеке/муксере. Естественно, нужно корректировать PTS/DTS.

Как использовать FFmpeg для декодирования/кодирования, муксинга/демуксинга можно в его документации, примерах. Для приведения к нужному формуту пикселя использовать swscale()